ggplot and global bathymetry map, missing axis and reference value for latitude and longitude
I'm using a code to plot the position of vents globally, using bathymetry from getNOAA.bathy and data from InterRidge vents database.
Anyway, my code for the plot is this:
    # Plot the map
    `base_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = global_batyf, aes(color = Depth)) +
    scale_fill_scico(palette = "broc", limits = c(-4000, 0)) +
    geom_sf(data = world, fill = "lightgray", color = NA) +
    coord_sf(crs = "+proj=robin")`
    # Add faceting based on Type variable in vents_sf dataset

    p1 <- base_map +
    new_scale_color() +
    geom_sf(data = vents_sf, aes(color = Activity, shape = Type), size = 0.8) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#2D936C", "#f9dc5c", "#cd4631")) +
    coord_sf(crs = "+proj=robin") +
    labs(title = "Global vents distribution - Robinson Projection",
       x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude") +
    geom_text(x = c(-170, -50, 130), y = c(85, 35, -60), label = c("Longitude: -180 0 180",          "Latitude: -90 -30 0 30 90"), hjust = 0, vjust = 0, size = 4, color = "gray50") +
  facet_wrap(~Type, labeller = as_labeller(c(`Deep-sea vent` = "Deep-sea vent distribution",    'Shallow vent' = "Shallow vent distribution"))) +
 theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
 strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12),
 plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "black"),
 axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
 axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

    print(p1)


The problem is that is coming outside like this:
enter image description here
I would like to have the axis with Long and Lat around the globe with reference values, do you have some suggestions or improvement?

Could you include the code to get data from getNOAA.bathy and the URL for the vents data?

This is a known issue with axis labels and non-conformal projections. Be sure to run library(dplyr) before running the code from the link in that previous comment.

@LTyrone partially, sure! I got the labels on the Y axis but not the X axis...anyway, probably I got how to change it just adapting the previous code, thank you!
